# Turning R scripts into a "data science tool"

Tags: r

I have R scripts that process a client's datasets (make figures, summary tables, etc). I'd like to package these scripts into a standalone program, aka data science tool, that I can give to the client and that requires **no interaction with code on their part**. Ideally they will open the tool, load data, click run, and be given reports. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you check shiny? https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

Comment: Do you have to bundle the whole of R in there as well, or do they install that first?

Answer (score 4):

You can refer below the answer to the similar question asked.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096520/compile-r-script-into-standalone-exe-file

Alternatively,
You can use R-shiny app for it. You can build application which can be deployed on website also. See below link for the examples of application made by R-shiny.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/

This way client will not be seeing your code at all and will be working on it just as a tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with user interface and server-side programming I strongly recommend you the shiny. Below a very nice walkthrough for your first nice shiny app.

https://rstudio.com/resources/webinars/how-to-start-with-shiny-part-1/

it is basically creating your r instructions on the same server that your customer can reach and creating a shiny app that is made of user-interface part and server instructions part and combining them as arguments in shinyApp() function.

Here is a nice cheat sheet of shiny.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/images/shiny-cheatsheet.pdf

it will take your couple days to deploy when you are done with Rstudio resoruces.